# My computer starts to randomly freeze after my GPU got burned

Tags: freeze, gpu

My computer started to randomly freeze after my GPU got burned. As of now I have already replaced my GPU, but this has not solved the problem. I already tried troubleshooting my PC, I tried reinstalling my OS, and using another HDD. I tried memtest, but it stops testing and I don’t know if it freezes because a text line is blinking just my keyboard and mouse is not responding, and I also tested my RAM on other computer so I am sure that the problem is not on my HDD or on my RAM.

It needs a hard reset to get out the freeze state and after that it won’t boot for a while. I need to wait for an hour or try to reseat all the components to boot it again. And some times I can use it for a day or two before it freezes again. And just the same process wait or try to reseat.

- Motherboard: Asus P5kpl-am se
- Processor: Pentium® Dual-core CPU E5200 2.5 GHz
- GPU: Gigabyte GT 730 2 GB 128-bit ddr3
- PSU: just generic 600 watts PSU

Comment: How exactly was the GPU "burned"? What was it doing at the time and what happened to it?

Comment: I was just browsing when a spark comes out and it starts to fire

Comment: If a component goes up in flames then all power components nearby are suspect. Possible candidates for replacement are your PSU and motherboard as they supply power to the graphics card. The flame-out could have also done some damage to the CPU, it's difficult to say.

Comment: what information I can give you for you to recognize what could be the problem. I am afraid of buying or replacing those all parts but the only problem is just one of them. I am kind a short in terms of money cause im just a student yet.

Comment: Personally, because your computer actually powers on and works then the PSU would be nearer the end of the list but still a suspect. I would change the motherboard to start with. The CPU is still on the list but if that was damaged you would experience problems very soon after switching it on... You must consider ALL components (PSU, MoBo, CPU and RAM) to be suspects, though.

Comment: i think we can remove the ram  on the list because my ram had been tested on other computer and works fine and i think my cpu is fine its just been 6 years since it was bought but  I want to know what specifically the problem because im short and can only buy the specific part right away but the problem what is that part if i bu the wrong part i will wait for a month to have money to buy another part

Comment: It could very well still be a PSU issue. If the psu surges occationally, that could cause the computer to lock up and could very well start a fire. i've had computers that boot fine but freeze after awhile and usually switching the power supply out fixes that

Comment: see if maybe you could bring it to some computer repair shop and just ask if you can borrow a power supply for a minute or two to see if you get the same issue. If you do, it's not the psu and you can give it back to them without spending money. If you don't get the same issue, buy it and you've solved your problem

Comment: @Abrahamlanggam When the system sparked did you turn it off and did the screen do crazy things ?